# Echo ACF Value in Woocommerce Email Template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have a field set with Advanced Custom Fields Pro that I am trying to echo in my admin-new-order.php template that is sent to administrators once a new order has been created.

I have a field setup with ACF called customer_number

The customer_number ACF field is displayed in the User/Edit User page where website administrators are able to give a unique customer number for this individual user.

What I'm trying to do is display this users customer number in the admin new order email that is sent.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
   <p>Customer #:<?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, 'customer_number', true ); ?></p>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: For ACF, use [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) 
opposite `get_post_meta()`

Comment: Just tried <?php echo get_field( $order_id, 'customer_number', true ); ?> and didn't work

Comment: Try `echo get_field('customer_number', 'user_' . wc_get_order($order_id)->get_user_id() )`